# How to find the ports of all running PostgreSQL instances (as a non-root user)

Tags: postgresql

I have a monitoring script (running as an unprivileged user) that needs to check all instances of Postgres currently running on the same host (Ubuntu Linux 18.04). Is there an easy way to find all their port numbers?

I was thinking of listing all files matching `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.*` but I'm not sure whether this is reliable or the easiest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way with Debian/Ubuntu would be to use [`pg_lsclusters`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pg_lsclusters.1.html) (as provided by the `postgresql-common` package).
This command lists the clusters with ports, statuses and other information:

```
$ pg_lsclusters 
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
11  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
12  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log

$ ports=$(pg_lsclusters --no-header | awk '{ print $3; }')

$ echo $ports
5433 5432
```

Comment: Perfect! That's just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
 ss -xpntl| grep postmaster
```

Comment: Thank you. `ss -xpntl |grep postgres` returns `u_strLISTEN 0       128              /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 53007754                                          * 0` - but is this more reliable somehow than just looking for socket files in /var/run/postgresql ?

Comment: I would say, yes. It's not guaranteed, that socket files will be located in the */var/run* directory. With *ss -x* you can see open socket files independent from their location.